# HIGHCHARTS How to add new Y category to Gantt Chart

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart with multiple swim lanes (Y categories') like this:

[image]

As you can see, I have a list of categories on the Y axis, one of them is empty (this is intentional meaning the empty is procurement part 2), our objective is:

1. add a button on top/left  that can run an action (in this case, ask the name of the new Y) BUT as you can see the button is not displayed correctly until we put the mouse over, please check the following images:
   [image]
   the button appears as follow in the corner top-left:
   [image]
   **but should be displayed like this:**
   [image]

what are we missing? or is this a bug in the app?

2. We are trying to **add a NEW lane (Y axis)** we tried 2 methods both do not report an error but simply do nothing... we noticed the list of categories is modified but the change is not reflected even if we call the redraw... and this is our code:

   chart.renderer.button('New Lane', 10, 10, function () {

   ```
        var yAxes = chart.axes.filter(f => f.coll == 'yAxis');

        var yAxis = yAxes[0];

        var cats = yAxis.categories;

        cats.push('SOMETHING');

        console.log(cats);

        yAxis.setCategories(cats, true);

        //yAxis.update({
        //    categories: cats
        //}, true);

    }).add();
   ```

**In other words:** We want to know why the button is not rendered correctly AND how to add a category to the Y axis.

Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

You used the button renderer method correctly to add the [button](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#button), now place it inside [chart.events.render](https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/chart.events.render).

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      render: function() {
        let chart = this,
          series = chart.series,
          plotLeft = chart.plotLeft,
          plotTop = chart.plotTop,
          plotWidth = chart.plotWidth;

        if (chart.myBtn) {
          chart.myBtn.destroy();
        }

        chart.myBtn = chart.renderer.button('button', plotLeft - 80, plotTop - 130, function() {
            console.log('your button');
          })
          .attr({
            'stroke-width': 1,
            stroke: 'green'
          })
          .add();
      }
    }
  },
```

How to set categories to yAxis you can achieve by method [setCategories](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setCategories) on Highcharts.Axis or updating yAxis with [update](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setCategories).

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dL6c2zrp/

Comment: Sebastian, thank you for your kind answer... in regards of the categories the method setCategories, as shown on our code, we used it, also tried the update method, no errors at all but simply not doing anything, not refreshing the page... what could be happening? would this be a bug?

Comment: Could you send a simplified version of your code in the online code editor? That would help debug the problem.

Comment: Ok, I have oploaded my code to https://jsfiddle.net/sipi_intel/s14qxe6w/27/

Here the button displays fine, when you click the button on the top-left that says "new lane", it seem to create the new Y category, but as you can see it does nothing... Thank you for any help you may bring.

Comment: @GuillermoPerez, a new line will not be added if there is nothing to display there. In order to solve this you have to add a mock point in that new line: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/eawy36fp/

Comment: @KarolKołodziej thank you for your awesome solution... now only 2 problems left.

Comment: @GuillermoPerez, please point out what you mean.